# Is there any solution for better fit beta prime distribution to data than using Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, estimation, goodness-of-fit

I was trying to fit beta prime distribution to my data using python. As there's `scipy.stats.betaprime.fit`, I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy.stats as sts
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N  = 5000
nb_bin = 100
a = 12; b = 106; scale = 36; loc = -a/(b-1)*scale
y = sts.betaprime.rvs(a,b,loc,scale,N)
a_hat,b_hat,loc_hat,scale_hat = sts.betaprime.fit(y)
print('Estimated parameters: \n a=%.2f, b=%.2f, loc=%.2f, scale=%.2f'%(a_hat,b_hat,loc_hat,scale_hat))

plt.figure()
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(y, nb_bin, normed=True)
pdf_ini = sts.betaprime.pdf(bins,a,b,loc,scale)
pdf_est  = sts.betaprime.pdf(bins,a_hat,b_hat,loc_hat,scale_hat)
plt.plot(bins,pdf_ini,'g',linewidth=2.0,label='ini');plt.grid()
plt.plot(bins,pdf_est,'y',linewidth=2.0,label='est');plt.legend();plt.show()
```

It shows me the result that:

```
Estimated parameters:
 a=9935.34, b=10846.64, loc=-90.63, scale=98.93
```

which is quite different from the original one and the figure from the PDF:

[image]

If I give the real value of `loc` and scale as the input of `fit` function, the estimation result would be better. Has anyone worked on this part already or got a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the original post does not fix the random number generator seed, so the problem is not reproducible. A reproducible version is:

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy.stats as sts
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng(83492456935469354704)

N  = 5000
nb_bin = 100
a = 12; b = 106; scale = 36; loc = -a/(b-1)*scale
y = sts.betaprime.rvs(a, b, loc, scale, N, random_state=rng)
a_hat, b_hat, loc_hat, scale_hat = sts.betaprime.fit(y)
print('Estimated parameters:\n'
      f'a={a_hat:.2f}, b={b_hat:.2f}, loc={loc_hat:.2f}, scale={scale_hat:.2f}')

plt.figure()
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(y, nb_bin, density=True)
pdf_ini = sts.betaprime.pdf(bins, a, b, loc, scale)
pdf_est = sts.betaprime.pdf(bins, a_hat, b_hat, loc_hat, scale_hat)
plt.plot(bins, pdf_ini, 'g', linewidth=2.0, label='ini'); plt.grid()
plt.plot(bins, pdf_est, 'y--', linewidth=2.0, label='est'); plt.legend(); plt.show()
```

[image]

The plot of the fitted PDF matches the original PDF closely. The parameters are different, but all we can expect a fitting function to do is optimize parameters to maximize or minimize some function of the data. This may or may not lead to a good estimate of the underlying parameters. We can see that `betaprime.fit` is doing its job here because it seeks to minimize the negative log-likelihood function (NLLF), and the NLLF increases when we perturb the parameter values from the values it converges to.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
ax = ax.ravel()

eps = np.linspace(-5, 5, 300)
params = dict(a=a_hat, b=b_hat, loc=loc_hat, scale=scale_hat)

for hi, axi, param_name in zip(np.eye(4), ax, params):
  param_values = list(params.values())
  nllfs = [stats.betaprime.nnlf(param_values + epsi*hi, y) for epsi in eps]
  axi.plot(eps, nllfs)
  axi.set_xlabel(f'perturbation to `{param_name}`')

fig.suptitle('Effect of parameter perturbations on NLLF')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

It seems that a variety of parameter values can give approximately the same value of the negative log-likelihood function, which is `nllf0 = 8101.751831213405` above. For instance, using `stats.fit` (which uses a stochastic optimizer), we can get several very different local optima, all with approximately the same value of the NLLF, if we run it several times.

```py
FitParams(a=16.437726024127105, b=55.11441645100978, loc=-4.464265239903504, scale=14.750853658609275) 8101.030972971992
FitParams(a=67.47536806626265, b=35.31736834983663, loc=-5.97011638305157, scale=3.044776624686649) 8102.577960289996
FitParams(a=39.76533774830455, b=37.594009970143354, loc=-5.467151220796732, scale=5.046462382947629) 8102.258806849436
FitParams(a=18.873466185063798, b=48.85176088955696, loc=-4.6217525946033, scale=11.760288109582378) 8101.294928499379
FitParams(a=14.430145578727348, b=61.61794106850824, loc=-4.300115416751307, scale=18.134272628062437) 8100.849263206925
```

So I'm not sure if there's much more to be done unless you can fix or provide tighter bounds for some of the parameter values based on knowledge of the problem. For instance, if you can provide reasonable bounds around the parameters, `scipy.stats.fit` can find a parameters with a better (lower) negative log-likelihood function than the original parameters.

```py
limits = np.asarray([-10, 10])
bounds = dict(a=a+limits, b=b+limits, loc=loc+limits, scale=scale+limits)
res = stats.fit(stats.betaprime, data=y, bounds=bounds)
ref = stats.betaprime.nnlf((a, b, loc, scale), y)
print(res.nllf(), res.params)
# 8100.411619791135 FitParams(a=11.830670229468097, b=98.43447339490054, loc=-4.094123769559834, scale=33.8539065644368)
print(ref, (a, b, loc, scale))
# 8100.927379232642 (12, 106, -4.114285714285714, 36)
```